# Should I add an undervoltage protection for lithium battery-powered projects?

Tags: battery-charging, low-battery, undervoltage

I am designing a board with a microcontroller (an ESP32) that will be in deep sleep most of the time. The board will run on a 1-cell lithium battery (not sure if I will use a Li-poly or a Li-ion).

While looking at existing design schematics ([Adafruit HUZZAH32](https://cdn-learn.adafruit.com/assets/assets/000/041/630/original/feather_schem.png), [SparkFun Thing Plus](https://cdn.sparkfun.com/assets/e/4/2/1/7/ESP32_Thing_Plus_v_2_0_Schematic.pdf), [DFRobot FireBeetle](https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/A1VO7RyKHzL.pdf)), I was shocked that these products doesn't integrate an under-voltage protection (or I missed it?) to stop the board from drawing any current below a threshold voltage.

Is it safe to do so? Is the under-voltage protection not required because most of the batteries have a built-in circuit for that? Also, is it possible to add under-voltage protection without adding BOM costs (e.g. using the *STAT* pin of the charge controller to drive the *ENABLE* pin of the regulator)?

Comment: Regarding your cost-free proposal, a basic charger won't look for end-of-discharge. In fact, a charger may not even be powered unless there's power coming into the charging port. Unless it was a full-featured PMIC that had charging and protection all in one IC. That said, protection IC's can be pretty cheap, probably under 50 cents at quantity, and adds the peace of mind that any single cell battery can be used, with or without internal protection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Over-discharging any rechargeable battery chemistry can ruin the cell(s).  Depending on how far below minimum the voltage is allowed to go, and for how long, the effect could range from somewhat reduced capacity & cycle life, to an unusable cell.

How likely is the user to remember to recharge the battery before it's empty?

If the product is in deep sleep most of the time, and wakes rarely to do something very low-power, a single full charge of the battery may last for months, even years.  Likely to be ignored until it stops working due to low battery.

There are several approaches.

1) Under-voltage protection circuit that effectively disconnects the battery from the circuit board (load), and keeps it disconnected until it has seen the battery go above threshold or receive a minimum amount of charge.  An additional chip at extra hardware cost, but maybe less software work.

2) Software in MCU could monitor battery voltage and lock out full wakeup (running main code or turning on circuit board features) after low battery voltage, until it has sensed a power adapter input applied, or battery voltage above threshold.  If MCU doesn't have ADC, can use low-cost voltage comparator into an input pin.

3) Device could warn user of moderately low battery (10-20% capacity remaining) by an intermittent beep, blinking light, network communication message.  If user ignores all warnings, they may need to replace the battery.

4) Add small solar panel or other energy capture, so the device can run perpetually under nominal conditions.  Manual battery recharge or replacement may still be necessary if a particular device is placed where there's not enough light.

Alternately,

5) Use a lithium primary battery large enough to last a long time.  The product becomes 'disposable' and is replaced (recycled) entirely when the battery runs out.  If the battery gets over-discharged, it doesn't matter, so long as it doesn't leak or cause other physical problems.  For example, smoke detectors now come with lithium primary large enough to last 10 years, instead of expecting the user to swap a 9V every year or two.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on whether you have a cell or a pack.  A cell (usually referred to as a battery) is only the element itself.  A pack contains a cell(s) but will have additional protection, usually including undervoltage protection as well as thermal sensors and sometimes charge management/coulomb counting circuitry.